# XPath in HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have the follow xpath '/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/h1' for 'http://stackoverflow.com/', that is 'Top Questions' header.

How to use it in HtmlAgilityPack?

```
var wc = new WebClient();
wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
var html = wc.DownloadString("http://stackoverflow.com/");
var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);
var node = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/h1");
```

returns null

Comment: Can you check downloaded page? Does it have expected structure?

Comment: Please, try this one: `//body/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/h1`.

Comment: Yep. And I have same problem with all xpaths on any htmls. So I want to know, may be there is some peculiar properties with xpath in agility pack? Sometimes it throws 'Expression must evaluate to a node-set.' excpetion

Comment: Probably some setup issue on your computer.  I copied your code directly and received nodes.  Check to make sure your html var has data?

Answer (score 1):

Works for me.  The .Dump() is just from using it in LinqPad.

```
var url = "http://stackoverflow.com/";
new HtmlWeb().Load(url)
             .DocumentNode
             .SelectSingleNode("/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/h1")
             .InnerText.Dump();
```

Result:

```
    Top Questions
```

With some spacing.